FlutterFlow: "How to Calculate Total Time and Calories in Firestore When Adding Completed Yoga Exercises"
I have a yoga app where users complete exercises and press a "complete" button to add the exercise to an array of maps within a Firestore document. Each exercise has a different duration (time) and calorie burn (kcal).
I want to calculate the total time and total kcal each time a new exercise is added to this array. My Firestore structure includes a document for each date. If today's date matches an existing document, I add the completed exercise to that document. If not, I create a new document for the current date and add the exercise to it.
How can I calculate the total_time and total_kcal when a new exercise is added to the array in Firestore?
[[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/6hT84CBM.png)](https://i.sstatic.neenter image description heret/WxGQNnZw.png)

When you add a new document you'll always have an exercise to add to its list, so then the total will be the duration and kcal of the exercise. When you add a new exercise to an existing document you'll just have to add the exercise's duration and kcal to the total.

totalDuration += exerciseDuration
totalKcal += exerciseKcal

